# c++ multiple operators calculator

Tags: c++, calculator, operator-keyword

So i'm trying to make a calculator that work with multiple operators. I've make some calculator programs that work with 2 numbers(used switch) but when i try with more than 2 numbers i can't really make it work. I have an idea how to do it but i can't implement it (i'm new to programming).This line is not working but this is what i think:result = a op[0] b op[1] c;
 So here's the code:

```
 // Simple arithmetic calculator.
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


int main()
{
   float a, b, c, result;
   char op[2];

   // Get numbers and mathematical operator from user input
   cin >> a >> op[0] >> b >> op[1] >> c;
result = a op[0] b op[1] c; // result = a + b - c if op[0]=+ and op[1]=-
   // Output result
   cout << result << endl;
   return 0;
}
```

here's the other code but is not working

```
// CalculatorSwitch.cc
// Simple arithmetic calculator using switch() selection.

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   float a, b, c, result;
   char operation,operation2;

   // Get numbers and mathematical operator from user input
   cin >> a >> operation >> b >> operation2 >> c;

   // Character constants are enclosed in single quotes
   switch(operation)
   {
   case '+':
         result = a + b;
         break;

   case '-':
         result = a - b;
         break;

   case '*':
         result = a * b;
         break;

   case '/':
         result = a / b;
         break;

   default:
         cout << "Invalid operation. Program terminated." << endl;
         return -1;
   }
   switch(operation2)
   {
   case '+':
         result = b + c;
         break;

   case '-':
         result = b - c;
         break;

   case '*':
         result = b * c;
         break;

   case '/':
         result = b / c;
         break;

   default:
         cout << "Invalid operation. Program terminated." << endl;
         return -1;
   }
}
```

so if i'm correct to use it with more than 2 numbers, i must create a second switch for the second operator, but i got wrong results.. so i want to make first code work.

Comment: You didn't notice that this wouldn't even compile?

Comment: if `switch` was working with two numbers, why don't you use e.g. `switch` here for three numbers??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic is wrong. In the first switch statement you set `result = a OP1 b`. In your second switch you set `result = b OP2 c`, completely overriding what the first switch did. Instead you have to work with the intermediate result, e.g. change your second switch to

```
switch(operation2)
{
case '+':
      result = result + c;
      break;

case '-':
      result = result - c;
      break;

case '*':
      result = result * c;
      break;

case '/':
      result = result / c;
      break;

default:
      cout << "Invalid operation. Program terminated." << endl;
      return -1;
}
```

Note however, that this is still incorrect, as it ignores the order of operations if the first operator is `+` or `-` and the second one is `*` or `/`.

To make the first code work, it takes more than this answer, creating a complete math parser is not at all trivial.